# Sort integer file names in Python

Tags: python, sorting, operating-system

I have file names as

[image]

When I iterate over them, it iterated in a string manner like:

```
1
10 
11
.
.
19
2
20
.. so on. I hope you got this.
```

I want to iterate them over as integers not strings. Please help  me write a function for it.

```
for i,file in enumerate(sorted(files),key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(file)[0]))
     #CODE
```

But gives an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-f667164b9d6e> in <module>
     
----> 6 for i,file in enumerate(sorted(files),key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(file)[0])):
     

TypeError: 'key' is an invalid keyword argument for enumerate()
```

Please help me write a function for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `key` is an argument to the `sorted` function.

Comment: That’s why I want to create a separate function, @AbdulNiyasPM help me please

Comment: you have `)` in wrong place - it has to be `sorted(files, key= ...)` but you have `sorted(files), key=...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try converting all your files to ints first, then sort them.

```py
import os

files = ['0.pdf', '1.pdf', '12.pdf', '15.pdf', '3.pdf', '2.pdf', ]

for i, file_as_number in enumerate(sorted(int(os.path.splitext(file)[0]) for file in files)):
    print(i, file_as_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
files = ['0.pdf', '1.pdf', '12.pdf', '15.pdf', '3.pdf', '2.pdf' ]
fileDict= {}
SortedFiles = []
for i in range(len(files)):
    fileDict[int(files[i].split('.')[0])] = files[i]
for i in sorted(list(fileDict.keys())):
    SortedFiles.append(fileDict[i])
print (SortedFiles)
```

['0.pdf', '1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '12.pdf', '15.pdf']